# Convert EPSG and vertical datum of a DEM file

Tags: gdalwarp, wgs84, epsg, gdaldem, egm2008

I have DEM files that are in EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 and use latitude and longitude for coordinates. The elevation units are in meter but use the WGS84 ellipsoid with WGS84 elevation. I want to convert these files to EPSG:7755 that uses WGS 84 as the geodetic CRS and a cartesian 2D coordinate system with axes: easting, northing (X,Y) and orientations: east, north and meters as units of measurement (see: https://epsg.io/7755) so I have my DEM files in meters instead of latitude - longitude, because I accurately want to compute the slopes via gdaldem (see: https://gdal.org/programs/gdaldem.html) which suggests to reproject the grid using gdalwarp before using gdaldem.

In addition, I want to convert the newly created EPSG:7755 files that still use the WGS84 ellipsoid to EGM2008 (as described here: https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/10/26/convert-between-orthometric-and-ellipsoidal-elevations-using-gdal/), so that I end up with dem files that use meters as units of measurement and geoid elevation.

I tried the gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:7755+3855 command (as EPSG:3855 is converting to EGM2008 height, see: https://epsg.io/3855), but the elevation values seem to be a bit off.

I am new to GIS and wonder if my reasoning is correct or whether the command I'm using is doing what I expect it to do.